# What math topic teaches you to optimize numerical computations?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I was recently reading *Trefethen & Bau - Numerical Linear Algebra*, when I came accross this paragraph:

> In fact, there is much more to the cost of an algorithm than operation counts. On a single-processor computer, the execution time is affected by competing jobs running on the same processor. On multiprocessor machines the situation becomes more complex, with communication between processors sometimes taking on an importance much greater than the actual "computation." With some regret, we shall ignore these important considerations, because this book is deliberately classical in style, focusing on algorithmic foundations.

So, is there a textbook that focuses on these issues from a mathematical perspective? What would the topic of study be? I originally thought numerical linear algebra was the course to start learning how to optimize numerical computations, but I was really disappointed after reading that paragraph.

Comment: Yes, I edited the OP. Feel free to edit it more if you think something else is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I originally thought numerical linear algebra was the course to start learning how to optimize numerical computations

Numerical linear algebra *is* a start for learning how to do optimized numerical computation. It just isn't an end. Trefethen's book is a solid introduction to the foundations of algorithmic design; algorithmic design is the most mathematical aspect of numerical computation, though not all of it is linear algebraic.

There are, however, many further (mathematical) topics in the field that you can pursue to further your understanding. Some broader coverage of numerical analysis is also helpful (see, for example, Higham's book [Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718027?mobileUi=0&)), as well as a wealth of literature on parallel computation, much of which is unfortunately still too state-of-the-art for there to be a single concise up-to-date textbook. During my own graduate studies I followed online materials from courses; see for example [UC Berkeley's parallel computation course](https://sites.google.com/lbl.gov/cs267-spr2020).

However, the reality of the situation is that numerical computation is not solely mathematical. We perform our computation not with abstract Turing machines, but with electronic computers. Therefore, the hardware constraints of specific electronic computer configurations become extremely important. As a simple example, one of the basic considerations to make when coding an algorithm is which data to store in memory for future recall. If performance is important, then these considerations are based upon physical access times to different forms of memory; modern CPUs have several levels of memory cache that are much smaller but have faster access time compared to the larger system memory. These access times are based upon the electronic wiring and can vary not only based on the particular model of CPU, but also on the physical manufacturing properties that can differ very slightly between individual CPUs of the same model.

Another large topic I encourage you to read into is GPU-based computation. Once again, the primary considerations are hardware-based rather than mathematical, based upon the highly parallel, shared-memory nature of GPUs.

Comment: Thanks that course you linked looks worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

Why disappointed? You still need everything in that book to do optimization well.  It’s a awesome book, even though much has happened since not was written.

I would imagine you just need a good book in parallel computing.  But unless you are really into some powerful computations, you will never even care about that.

A lot of modern software automatically parallelizes computations under the hood, and you never have to care about the details.

Possibly someday you want to design a powerful parallel algorithm, and then you would  need to understand parallel programming and computing.

Comment: You said: "It’s a awesome book, even though much has happened since not was written." Where could one find the highlights of "much has happened since..."?

Comment: @Frank no idea, I personally did not need more